# Can you find the missing words? 7 anagram puzzles

Tags: word, anagram

Inspired by QuantumTwinkie's Anagram Puzzles, the rules are simple. Find the anagram pair that fits into the two blanks for each numbered item. The number of spaces is irrelevant. And go!

> 1. Yeah right you’ll get _____ under that tree, maybe when ______ freezes over.
> 2. Among the sales team, Charlie & Matt always ______ the pack in terms of ______ flow.
> 3. What a harsh _____ to my argument – that guy is a no-good _____.
> 4. As we approach the waterfall, please do not _____ on the _____, for the sake of all our olfactory senses.
> 5. How salacious his desires for gluten – he  _____ it all for a slice of _____.
> 6. My grandma took a handful of _____, that’s why she took a _____ down the stairs.
> 7. Go take your _____ out on the shooting _____.

Comment: There's always this 1 universal word that fits all blanks, I hope that's not the answer

Comment: @Alex What is it?

Comment: @Alex that's not it. No repeats. I'm curious too. What's the word?

Comment: Yay someone used my puzzle template! I am flattered! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1:

> SHADE, HADES

For 3:

> RETORT, ROTTER

For 5:

> BARED, BREAD

Comment: all three of these are correct...and this rounds out the answers for this puzzle with the remainder answered by King Dedede's Secret Assistant

Comment: Great job! Especially for #1, since I could not think of a good answer and didn't even remember that Hades is another word for Hell.

Answer (score 5):

1.

> shade and Hades

2.

> lead and deal

3.

> retort and rotter

4.

> fart and raft

5.

> bared and bread

6.

> pills and spill

7.

> anger and range

Comment: 4 & 7 are correct. #1 is kindaaaa close, but you're overthinking it a bit.

Comment: #2 is also correct

Comment: #6 is correct as well